# How do you set the NODE namespace with NuSoap?

Tags: php, soap, nusoap

Is there a way in NUSOAP to set a node's namespace?

Using normal PHP soap, it can be done with SoapVar.

What is the equivalent in NuSoap?

I have:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:own="www.ownyourliferewards.co.za" xmlns:own1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/OwnYourLife.WebServices.WebServicesBase" xmlns:own2="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/OwnYourLife.WebServices.Generic.DataObjects">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <AuthenticateMember xmlns="www.ownyourliferewards.co.za">
            <request>
                <SecurityToken>9415CD31-0C7E-40AB-A45F-D3538B98B96B</own1:SecurityToken>
                <MembershipNumber>200803407801</own2:MembershipNumber>
            </request>
        </AuthenticateMember>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

and I want:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:own="www.ownyourliferewards.co.za" xmlns:own1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/OwnYourLife.WebServices.WebServicesBase" xmlns:own2="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/OwnYourLife.WebServices.Generic.DataObjects">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <AuthenticateMember xmlns="www.ownyourliferewards.co.za">
            <request>
                <own1:SecurityToken>9415CD31-0C7E-40AB-A45F-D3538B98B96B</own1:SecurityToken>
                <own2:MembershipNumber>200803407801</own2:MembershipNumber>
            </request>
        </AuthenticateMember>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

(note the own1: and own2: namespaces on the nodes)

Thanks

Jacques